# What is the best way to get my windows 7 updates and programs on a new hard drive?

Tags: windows-7, backup

I recently had a problem with my 64GB SSD - and the thing is dead. Fortunately, I keep all of my important stuff on other drives - and only lost a few desktop shortcuts and my windows 7 installation.

Since I use my computer daily for my business, I needed something ASAP to work with. I clean installed windows 7 on a storage drive (300gb, 7200rpm) and did all of the system updates, and installed virus/malware/etc. protection

I plan to purchase a new SSD - but hate to have to install everything again. If I create a backup of the current system via control panel->system and security-> Backup and Restore - can I simply "restore" that backup to the new hard drive? Or will I have to completely re-install the O/S?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is what a backup is for. You will be fine if you do it that way. It would be easier just to clone the drive you have then copy the image over.

Comment: Aye.  1TB Harddrives are 70 bucks as Fry's